# sudo apt-get update cancelled half way through, now cannot run sudo apt-get update

Tags: apt, updates, repository

I'm a new user of ubuntu. It's been working fairly well so far. Today I've tried doing 'sudo apt-get update' and it's freezing after fetching data. This is the output:

```
sudo apt-get update 
Hit:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [94.5 kB]    
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [92.2 kB]
Fetched 187 kB in 0s (225 kB/s)
```

Using `sudo apt-get clean` and then `sudo apt-get update`, I get the following issue:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

Using `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/lock` and then `sudo apt-get update` I get a new issue:

```
** (appstreamcli:3466): WARNING **: Exception: Unable to get write lock on /var/cache/app-info/xapian/default: already locked
```

```
sudo fuser /var/cache/app-info/xapian/default
```

shows nothing.

```
file /var/cache/app-info/xapian/default
```

shows

```
/var/cache/app-info/xapian/default: directory
```

Comment: sudo apt-get clean and then retry.

Comment: I just tried that but got a new issue with a lock file

Comment: if you are sure no other process is accesing, then is it just to delete the lock. sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/lock

Comment: with that I get another lock issue on var/cache/app-info/xapian/default

Comment: add output of sudo fuser /var/cache/app-info/xapian/default , if the output is empty and the command; file /var/cache/app-info/xapian/default   Shows something like filepath: empty. Try delete that one aswell.

Comment: sudo fuser /var/cache/app-info/xapian/default shows nothing. file /var/cache/app-info/xapian/default shows /var/cache/app-info/xapian/default: directory. should I still delete it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40034/discussion-between-anders-f-u-kiaer-and-chris).

Comment: It's driving me crazy, what the hell happens to Ubuntu? No matter how I change the server or apt clean, it just won't work!!

Comment: Someone has reported the bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1583854

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process). I ran into the could not get lock issue the other day and resolved it with the same answer that Faheem Mitha used.

```
ps aux | grep apt
```

This will return a list of things that apt is doing with PIDs. Then run:

```
kill processnumber
```

or

```
kill -9 processnumber
```

You may or may not have to invoke sudo priveleges in order to kill the process depending on your setup.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah,I have the Same Problem, the Solve(I am not Sure it is) of mine is:

1. Restart the System
2. `killall` the relative Process
3. `sudo apt-get upgrade`
4. then you could install normally
5. Done! It Works.

Comment: Although you can upgrade, you still can't update!

Comment: @JulianLai I think It is a Bug about the 16.04, Report

Comment: Someone has reported it: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1583854

Answer (score 0):

A temporary fix for now is to simply delete everything under `/var/cache/app-info/xapian/default`. It appears to be the search index for `apt`, so it will have to be rebuilt, but no ill effects otherwise.