# I cannot run apt update properly - apt update hangs

Tags: apt

Version: Ubuntu 16.04

I have used it some weeks, but now it gives me this message when I'm trying to install software and update or upgrade:

```
Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
/var/lib/apt/lists/ locked
```

followed by this:

[Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1986288).

and another error:

```
** (appstreamcli:4560): WARNING **: Exception: Unable to get write lock on /var/cache/app-info/xapian/default: already locked
```

What should I do?

Comment: There are two process using aptd:`root      2461  0.0  0.7 291024 97620 ?        SNl  08:44   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/sbin/aptd
root      2740  0.0  0.3 291024 40012 ?        SN   08:44   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/sbin/aptd`. I killed them but does not work.

Comment: I can't do sudo apt update either, no matter I change the server or do apt clean.

Comment: I'm not the only one:[sudo apt-get update cancelled half way through, now cannot run sudo apt-get update](http://askubuntu.com/questions/774920/sudo-apt-get-update-cancelled-half-way-through-now-cannot-run-sudo-apt-get-upda)

Comment: Someone has reported the bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1583854

Comment: Yet, how cound I fix it if install and update does not work?

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/775049/16-04-apt-update-never-ends --- detail and fix in my answer

Answer (score 7):

I just encountered the same issue. The solution is to delete away the lock files in the xapian/default folder:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/app-info/xapian/default/flintlock /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally this means that the update process is already running. But in this special case it seems to be a temporarily problem with the Ubuntu repositories update servers today. When you start the computer, the system searches for updates automatically. When you run `sudo apt update` manually at the same time you receive this message. Today the reason is different, there seems to be an `appstream` bug. Even when the update process is not running and you execute `sudo apt update` the process does not complete successfully and the CPU usage gets stuck on 100%. As a workaround -> disable the `xenial-backports` repository and run `sudo apt update` again. Now the error should be gone. The bug already has been reported and confirmed on Launchpad.

[image]

Reference - bug reports addressing the issue on Launchpad - already confirmed by several users :

[Refresh hangs indefinitely, appstreamcli using 100% CPU](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appstream/+bug/1579712)  and [apt-get update hangs after hit/get](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appstream/+bug/1583862)

**Update information 2016-05-20 11.00 UTC : solution available in Ubuntu repositories**

A fix has been released : `appstream 0.9.4-1ubuntu1` `libappstream3 0.9.4-1ubuntu1`.

After having upgraded to this `appstream` version you can re-enable `xenial-backports`.

Answer (score -1):

You can find out which process(es) have `/var/cache/app-info/xapian/default` locked with `lsof`, then kill them with `kill` or `pkill`. However, if the program (`aptd` in this case) relies on the mere existence of `/var/cache/app-info/xapian/default` file, you will have to `sudo /bin/rm /var/cache/app-info/xapian/default` before trying again.

Comment: Isn't that a folder? In which case you'll have to use the -R flag.