# Apt-get does not complete after fetching sources

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager

I upgraded to 16.04 from 15.10 today.  Now I can no longer perform software updates. Running `sudo apt-get update` results in the following:

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [94.5 kB]
Hit:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease              
Fetched 94.5 kB in 1s (83.7 kB/s)
```

and it just sits there.  I left it like this for 4 hours.

Top shows that after running the command, `appstreamcli` goes to 100% cpu and stays there.

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                       
6741 root     20   0  120556  37456   9340 R  99.7  0.5   1:22.71 appstreamcli
```

Looks like I may not be the only one experiencing this...

Comment: Probably related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/774953/appstreamcli4560-warning-exception-unable-to-get-write-lock-on-var-cac, http://askubuntu.com/questions/774920/sudo-apt-get-update-cancelled-half-way-through-now-cannot-run-sudo-apt-get-upda/774939#774939

Comment: There seems to be a bug that is affecting newly installed or upgraded systems but not older 16.04 installs. I have the problem on an install I did yesterday but not on 2 from a couple of weeks ago. Find the bug on launchpad (linked in one of the other quesions) and mark as Affects Me Too

Comment: Thanks to both of you.  I'm seeing the same issue on another machine (upgraded weeks ago)  that was working fine yesterday.  So strange.  Will definitely flag the bug as affects me too.

Comment: Here is the bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1583862

Comment: As a workaround, disabling the "unsupported updates (xenial-backports)" as a source in seems to work for me.