# Installation is retrieving file 56 of 56, for AGES!

Tags: system-installation

How long am I going to have to wait for this to finish installing?

Comment: Probably related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/774920/sudo-apt-get-update-cancelled-half-way-through-now-cannot-run-sudo-apt-get-upda

Comment: Yup, experiencing the same problem here.

Comment: same issue here. after a few trials or restarting, the installation was complete but it could not restart shows error:
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector ......bla bla
and a dozen other similar errors

Answer (score 0):

You might try disabling networking and restarting the installation.

I experienced the same problem you described while installing Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 LTS (64-bit) in Hyper-V under Windows 10. The installation got to "Retrieving file 56 of 56" and nothing further happened.

The solution for me was to temporarily disable networking. Since I was installing in Hyper-V, it was just a matter of stopping the VM, disabling networking in Hyper-V Manager's Settings, and restarting the VM. Upon restarting, the Ubuntu installer detected an existing copy of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS as being installed (from the prior unfinished attempt), and I selected the option to erase the existing instance of the OS and re-install it. This time the installer successfully completed the installation, ending with the expected message that the system must be restarted. I turned networking back on in Hyper-V Manager settings and restarted. A fully working copy of Ubuntu is now up and running for me. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact problem while working on a dual boot Windows 7 / Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 LTS (64-bit) installation.  I also resolved the issue by disabling my internet connection and redoing the install. I think it might have been because I had the option to "check for updates during installation" checked. when I re-ran the installation (overwriting the prior unfinished installation that the installer detected) without that update box checked, it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying a complete install on a desktop.  After reading the previous posts I unplugged the network cable from the machine, which prevented me from selecting the check for updates box. The install went smoothly after that.